# How can I check state is different from the props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a props for example "shop_name" (this getting from redux). And I have to check this props different from my state's "shop_name" and disable my button.

For now i'm checking via this method;

```
isChanged() {
  const changedShopName = this.state.shop_name !== this.props.shop_name;

  return changedShopName;
}
```

And i'm passing new state with onchange func. and saving with this save func.;

```
onChange(event) {
  const name = event.target.name;
  const value = event.target.value;

  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
}

saveSellerInfos() {
  const data = {
    shop_name: this.state.shop_name,
  };

  this.props.saveSellerInformations(data);
}
```

And here is my button with disabled field;

```
<Button
        onClick={this.saveSellerInfos}
        disabled={!this.isChanged()}
        label={t('Save')}
        className={styles.save}
      />
```

After the save function this props is not updating normally. How can i check nextProps after the save function and disabled my button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` encapsulated in `Button` is not what you think it is, you will need to use `.bind` . as described here:  https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Comment: Yes, i'm binding all my methods. Thats working fine before the save method. When i save new state and ischanged dosent work expected. Because props is not changing without the re-call load method..

Comment: your redux store props should be updated when you are in the rendering state, can you send your code that connects to redux store .  (mapStateToProps)

Comment: Also this tool https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en .  will help you understand if the action is dispatched and if the store was updated as you expected

Comment: Thank you @Eran , I missed the saveActin.success method on my reducer... I just created this success method and passed data and state, thats working fine! :)